# Loading file to string, no such file?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script to thoroughly mutilate images, and to do so, I'm replacing every "g" in the file's text with an "h" (for now, it will likely change). Here's the beginning, and it's not working:

```
pathToFile = raw_input('File to corrupt (drag the file here): ')

x = open(pathToFile, 'r')
print x
```

After giving the path (dragging file into the terminal), this is the result:

```
File to corrupt (drag the file here): /Users/me/Desktop/file.jpeg 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/corrupt.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = open(pathToFile, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Desktop/file.jpeg '
```

How can the file not exist if it's right there, and I'm using the *exact* filename?

Comment: That path looks iffy - leading `/` normally means from the root directory, was that what you wanted? The path looks like a windows one however, so I'd expect it to start with a drive letter.

Comment: It's OSX; I want to work from the root directory because using ~/ in python requires at least 2 other libraries I don't really need. It's much quicker using / if you ask me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closely: `'/Users/me/Desktop/file.jpeg '`. There's a space in your filename. `open` doesn't do any stripping.

```
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write('a')
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('foo.txt ', 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt '
```

Comment: pathToFile = raw_input('File to corrupt (drag the file here): ').strip() can be a way to avoid this

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that! As far as I know, that's never been a problem for me before...